# Тире в простому реченні

Tags: пунктуація

У Ганни Чубач є вірш "Матері лист напишу". Строфа з нього:

> Матері лист напишу.
>   Щиро про все розпитаю.
>   Літери — круглі,
>   Moвa — чітка.
>   Мати — помалу читає.

В останньому рядку між підметом і присудком стоїть тире. Згідно з правилами чинного [Правопису](http://pravopys.kiev.ua/pravopys.aspx?SectionID=2186), для тире між головними членами речення є такі випадки:

> 1. Тире ставиться між підметом і присудком, коли останній виражений
>   іменником або кількісним числівником у називному відмінку, а
>   дієслова-зв'язки немає. При цьому присудок може бути як непоширеним,
>   так і поширеним.
>
> 2. Між підметом і присудком, коли один із цих членів речення (або
>   обидва) є інфінітивом.
>
> 3. Перед це (це є), оце, то, ось, (це) значить, якщо присудок,
>   виражений іменником у називному відмінку або неозначеною формою
>   дієслова, приєднується за допомогою цих слів до підмета.
>
> 4. На місці пропущеного члена речення, переважно присудка.
>
> 17. Взагалі для означення спеціально підкреслюваної паузи різного
>   змістового й стилістичного характеру.

Осільки в останній частині складного речення підмет виражений іменником, а присудок — особовою формою дієслова, право на тире у данному випадку надається лише правилом № 17. Але чи надається якийсь змістовий чи стилістичний нюанс цим знаком пунктуації?

Comment: А чому Ви інші пункти того переліку пропустили? Зокрема «[17](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil5.htm#par121p17). Взагалі для означення спеціально підкреслюваної паузи різного змістового й стилістичного характеру». Здається, це і була б відповідь за запитання…

Comment: @Sahsa, Ви праві. Я поширю питання